# How to open a Bootstrap modal window using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap modal window functionality. When someone clicks submit on my form, I want to show the modal window upon clicking the "submit button" in the form.

```
<form id="myform" class="form-wizard">
    <h2 class="form-wizard-heading">BootStap Wizard Form</h2>
    <input type="text" value=""/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#myform').on('submit', function(ev) {
    $('#my-modal').modal({
        show: 'false'
    }); 


    var data = $(this).serializeObject();
    json_data = JSON.stringify(data);
    $("#results").text(json_data); 
    $(".modal-body").text(json_data); 

    // $("#results").text(data);

    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1797, accepted):

Bootstrap has a few functions that can be called manually on modals:

```
$('#myModal').modal('toggle');
$('#myModal').modal('show');
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

You can see more here: [Bootstrap modal component](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#modals)

Specifically the [methods section](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods).

So you would need to change:

```
$('#my-modal').modal({
    show: 'false'
});
```

to:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

If you're looking to make a custom popup of your own, here's a suggested video from another community member:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zK4nXa84Km4

Answer (score 116):

Most often, when `$('#myModal').modal('show');` doesn't work, it's caused by having included jQuery twice. Including jQuery 2 times makes modals not to work.

Remove one of the links to make it work again.

Furthermore, some plugins cause errors too, in this case add

```
jQuery.noConflict(); 
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Answer (score 102):

In addition you can use via data attribute

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Launch modal</button>
```

In this particular case you don't need to write javascript.

You can see more here: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

Answer (score 25):

Just call the modal method(without passing any parameters) using `jQuery` selector.

Here is example:

```
$('#modal').modal();
```

Comment: Seems that `show` is the default parameter to `modal()` but I cannot find it [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#modals-options)

Answer (score 19):

If you use links's onclick function to call a modal by jQuery, the "href" can't be null.

For example:

```
... ...
<a href="" onclick="openModal()">Open a Modal by jQuery</a>
... ...
... ...
<script type="text/javascript">

function openModal(){

    $('#myModal').modal();
}       
</script>
```

The Modal can't show.
The right code is :

```
<a href="#" onclick="openModal()">Open a Modal by jQuery</a>
```

Answer (score 19):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("mybtn").click(function () {
            $("#my-modal").modal("show");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 17):

Here is how to load bootstrap alert as soon as the document is ready. It is very easy just add

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myModal").modal();
});
```

I made a [demo](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FIXH7FBJ6Y6T) on W3Schools.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Here is how to load a bootstrap modal as soon as the document is ready </h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->


  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#myModal").modal();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13):

Try to use **jQuery** instead of **$** sign when calling the function, it worked in my case as you can see below.

```
jQuery.noConflict(); 
jQuery('#myModal').modal('show');
```

**jQuery.noConflict();**  because when jQuery('#myModal').modal('show'); doesn't work, it's caused by having included jQuery twice. Including jQuery 2 times makes modals not to work. and it would resolve the problem in that case, as in my case it is repeating.

Further you can go to this link

[Bootstrap Model Window Not Showing by Calling Through JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53697389/bootstrap-model-window-not-showing-by-calling-through-jquery)

Answer (score 11):

Check out the complete solution here:

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_modal_show&stacked=h

Make sure to put libraries in required order to get result:

1- First bootstrap.min.css 2- jquery.min.js 3- bootstrap.min.js

(In other words jquery.min.js must be call before bootstrap.min.js)

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script> 

 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 10):

I tried several methods which failed, but the below worked for me like a charm:

```
$('#myModal').appendTo("body").modal('show');
```

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
$("#myModal").modal("toggle")
```

To open or close the modal with id myModal.

If the above is not working then it means bootstrap.js has been overridden by some other js file.
Here is a solution

1:- Move bootstrap.js to the bottom so that it will override other js files.

2:- Make sure the order is like below

```
<script src="plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Other js files -->
<script src="plugins/jQuery/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There should be a semicolumn at the end, preferabley. $("#myModal").modal("toggle");

Answer (score 5):

```
<form id="myform" class="form-wizard">
    <h2 class="form-wizard-heading">BootStap Wizard Form</h2>
    <input type="text" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" id="submitButton"/>
</form>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can launch the modal with the code below this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitButton").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

## Try This

> myModal1 is the id of modal

```
$('#myModal1').modal({ show: true });
```

Answer (score 3):

**Bootstrap 4.3** - more [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/)

```js
$('#exampleModal').modal();
```

```html
<!-- Initialize Bootstrap 4 -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<!-- MODAL -->

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    
      <div class="modal-body">
        Hello world   
      </div>
      
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's works for me well.

```js
function clicked(item) {
         alert($(item).attr("id"));
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-rtl/3.4.0/css/bootstrap-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="clicked(this);" id="modalME">Click me</button>

<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="modalME" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2>Modal in CSS</h2>
        <a href="#close" class="btn-close" aria-hidden="true">×</a> <!--CHANGED TO "#close"-->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One modal example here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#close" class="btn">Nice!</a>  <!--CHANGED TO "#close"-->
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /Modal -->
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above worked for me in Bootstrap 4.5.

This was the most effective way that I found to ensure that a modal opened from another modal is placed on top.

Add this to your CSS:

```css
/* Use this for Stacked Modals in BS 4.5 */
.modal:nth-of-type(even) {
    z-index: 1052 !important;
}

.modal-backdrop.show:nth-of-type(even) {
    z-index: 1051 !important;
}
```

Simply call your modal from JQuery:

```js
$('#modCommissionItemApplied').modal('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

For BS4 or BS5

If your have modal window has `id="commentsDocument"`

```js
// Open modal window  
$("#commentsDocument").modal("show")

// Hide modal window  
$("#commentsDocument").modal("hide")
```