# Display Bootstrap Modal using javascript onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I need to be able to open a Twitter bootstrap modal window using the `onClick=""` or similar function. Just need the code to go into the `onClick=""`. I am trying to make a click-able `div` to open the modal.

Code Excerpts:

**Div Code:**

```
<div class="span4 proj-div" onClick="open('GSCCModal');">
```

**Modal Div Code:**

```
<div id="GSCCModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

**Javascript:**

```
function open(x){
    $(x).modal('show');
}
```

Comment: Using onClick is largely frowned upon. Is there a specific reason you could not, at the least, include a script in a <script> tag?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the built in bootstrap functionality? (ie: put data-toggle="modal" and data-target="#foo" on your div?)

Comment: I am using the onClick to avoid using links around the div. And these are code excerpts, not how they actually are in the code.

@BriAnna
    you mean on the non-modal div code? I did not realize This would do anything, or that I could even do that.

Comment: Yep. Any element can be the clickable trigger. Just add the two attributes to your div. An a tag isn't required. But your markup isn't right. You have to follow Twitter Bootstrap's example.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You don't need an onclick. Assuming you're using Bootstrap 3 [Bootstrap 3 Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

```
<div class="span4 proj-div" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GSCCModal">Clickable content, graphics, whatever</div>

<div id="GSCCModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;  </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you're using Bootstrap 2, you'd follow the markup here: 
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

Comment: That, sir is exactly what I needed. I am currently using bootstrap 2.3.2, but it still works perfectly! Thank you!

Comment: What if I have to open model on another button click?

Comment: I get it.  [How to open a Bootstrap modal window using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183630/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-window-using-jquery)

Answer (score 15):

I was looking for the onClick option to set the title and body of the modal based on the item in a list. T145's answer helped a lot, so I wanted to share how I used it.

Make sure the  tag containing the JavaScript function is of type text/javascript to avoid conflicts:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function showMyModalSetTitle(myTitle, myBodyHtml) {

   /*
    * '#myModayTitle' and '#myModalBody' refer to the 'id' of the HTML tags in
    * the modal HTML code that hold the title and body respectively. These id's
    * can be named anything, just make sure they are added as necessary.
    *
    */

   $('#myModalTitle').html(myTitle);
   $('#myModalBody').html(myBodyHtml);

   $('#myModal').modal('show');
}</script>
```

This function can now be called in the onClick method from inside an element such as a button:

```
<button type="button" onClick="javascript:showMyModalSetTitle('Some Title', 'Some body txt')"> Click Me! </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

A JavaScript function must first be made that holds what you want to be done:

```
function print() { console.log("Hello World!") }
```

and then that function must be called in the onClick method from inside an element:

```
<a onClick="print()"> ... </a>
```

You can learn more about modal interactions directly from the Bootstrap 3 documentation found here:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Your modal bind is also incorrect. It should be something like this, where "myModal" = ID of element:

```
$('#myModal').modal(options)
```

In other words, if you truly want to keep what you already have, put a "#" in front GSCCModal and see if that works.

It is also not very wise to have an onClick bound to a div element; something like a button would be more suitable.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem.. Even using the twitter bootstrap functions, The farthest I get is a blank screen. I will also update my initial question with code I am currently working with

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after researching a lot, I finally built a js function to create modals dynamically based on my requirements. Using this function, you can create popups in one line such as:

```
puyModal({title:'Test Title',heading:'Heading',message:'This is sample message.'})
```

Or you can use other complex functionality such as iframes, video popups, etc.

Find it on https://github.com/aybhalala/puymodals For demo, go to http://pateladitya.com/puymodals/