# Display Bootstrap Modal using javascript onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

How do I add a bootstrap modal in the the javascipt on click. So far I was only able to alert ("hello") on click. How do i prompt out a modal box?

```
 graph.on("click", function (params) {
       var node = params['nodes'][0];
       displayInfo=false;
       if(node!=null){
        console.log('node:'+ params['nodes'][0]);
         x = params["pointer"]['canvas']['x'];
         y = params["pointer"]['canvas']['y'];   

         displayInfo=true;
         lastNode = nodes.get(node);
         lastClick = params['pointer'];
         //console.log(node);   
       }
       alert("hello");

       //add boostrap modal here    
     });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap modals: how to open with onClick=""](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20111219/bootstrap-modals-how-to-open-with-onclick)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an onclick.

```
<div class="span4 proj-div" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#GSCCModal">Clickable content, graphics, whatever</div>

<div id="GSCCModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;  </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need an onclick event anyhow, use it like below:

```
    graph.on("click", function (params) {
$('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

Reference: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 0):

- Create modal HTML and assign id for it, for example "my_modal"
  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo
- show the modal at the js using the code:

  $("#my_modal").modal('show');

Comment: Co incidently we just shared same answer pal  :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use id like

```
$("#modal-id").modal("show");
```

Or you can use class name `$(".modal-class").modal("show");`

Answer (score 0):

First make the modal pop up div then , Configure and use .modal('show')
For eg:-

```
 <a href="" data-target="#modalDiv" data-toggle="modal"> You can also use onClick call for jquery here.  </a>
  <div id="modalDiv">
       //some content
  </div>
```

In jquery use ,

```
     $("#modalDiv").modal('show');
```

Check this http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo