# Modal on jquery hover function

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to try a small trick to improve the bounce rate from my website. When the user is moving the cursor on the first 5px from the top of the page I suppose that he want to leave the page so I want to give him a modal with a search box or with some related articles.

So here we are:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#test" ).hover(function() {
        //alert("testing the mouseover");
        return false;
});  
});
```

`#test` is the id of that 5px div from the top of the page that I was talking about.

The problem is that I don't know how to replace the alert with my bootstrap modal.

```html
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#test" ).hover(function() {
           $('.modal').modal({
        show: true
    });
  });  
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4556/)

Comment: hi, i tried this and it doesn't work. The content of the modal will be displayed on the same page. May I know what is the version of the Jquery you are using for this example? and Is bootstrap necessary in this case?Thank you!

Comment: $(selector).hover(function(){ $(modalSelector).modal('show') });  **Note :** selector -  id or class of element to show  , modalSelector - Id or class of modal to show

Answer (score 1):

I would put an id on your modal and then do this in place of your alert

```
$('#modalid').modal('show');
```

You could also do this by class but I am not sure if any of the classes you have listed are unique to this specific modal

Answer (score 1):

First you need to give your modal an id, then trigger it to open on the desired hover (where your alert is now). Bootstrap has a few functions that can be called manually on modals, [you can read more about them on this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183630/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-window-using-jquery)