# How to open bootstrap modal without button-click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I need to popup a bootstrap modal in the success function of ajax in my page.The success function is called when the form is submitted.., so is there any method to popup the bootstrap modal without a button click.I'm a rookie.., please help me out here..
This is my ajax call..

```
     $("#form").submit(function(e)
   {
       $.ajaxSetup({
           headers:{'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content')}
       });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    console.log(postData);


    var formURL =  "http://localhost:8000/v1/people_roles";

    $.ajax(
    {


        url :formURL ,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        success:function(response, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {

        if(response.parent==1)
        {
            $("#getCode").html(response);
            $("#getCodeModal").modal('show');
             window.location.href="/web/staff/detail.php?id="+response.people_id;
        }
        else
        {
            //console.log(response);
            window.location.href="/web/staff/detail.php?id="+response.people_id;
        }
    }



    });   
    });
```

and this is my html modal code..

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="getCodeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
     <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
         <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
         <p><strong>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy</strong> text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
             printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
             remaining essentially unchanged.</p>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" ng-click="cancel()">Close</button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">Save changes</button>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you fiddle your code please?

Comment: `$("#getCodeModal").modal("show");`

Answer (score 28):

`$("#getCodeModal").modal('show');`

you can refer to this for more info:
[How to open a Bootstrap modal window using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183630/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-window-using-jquery)