# Button inside slickgrid to call modal with another slickgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid, bootstrap-modal

This is based on slickgrid example 1. I would like to have the button inside slickgrid call another instance of slickgrid in another modal. At the moment i am unable to interact with the button inside the grid aside from getting it to display. 
Here is my fiddle [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Domt301/q1cyrnm5/)

```
 {id: "newgrid", name: "newgrid", field: "newgrid", width: 80, sortable: true, formatter:reportFormatter}

function reportFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
  return "<button class='show-report'>show</button>";
}
```

Ive tried to use

```
 myGrid.onClick.subscribe(function(e,args) {
 if ($(e.target).hasClass('show-report')) {
    alert("hello");
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the onClick subscribe like this instead (and also right after it has been instantiated)

```
grid.onClick.subscribe(function(e,args) {
 if ($(e.target).hasClass('show-report')) {
    alert("hello");
 }
});
```

Since the grid instance is like this

`grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);`

Comment: That worked perfectly, any ideas on how i could link a modal to that button? Much like the one that initiated the grid to begin with?

Comment: that seems to be a bigger question itself. For starters, try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183630/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-window-using-jquery