# Dialog (popup) bootstrap rendered by MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstap table to present collection. In my table last column is button for details. After click on it, I want to display dialog, which will be filled by model from MVC action.

So, how can I do this:

1. Click on button in row (there is <a href='**MVC_action**\ROW_ID'>
2. **MVC_action** will be executed and return model
3. Model is pass to view and dialog is visible with filled data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do not use `<a href>` for the button. That will make a refresh on the page. Instead, create a button and add a javascript event handler, like `<button onclick="detail(ROW_ID)">`
2. The `detail()` function will call **MVC_action**\ROW_ID. The result from this call must be injected in a hidden div which handles the bootstrap dialog.
3. **MVC_action** returns a partial view with the content of the dialog.
4. After the injection, you must open the dialog.

[Here you can see an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183630/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-window-using-jquery) of an ajax call and a Bootstrap modal.

Greetings