# On specific option selection from drop down menu a modal form should pop up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been trying to pop up a modal from

[image]

Whenever user select option c from drop down menu 
[image]

Code Snap::
Modal Form

```
<div id="loginmodal" style="display:none;">
    <h1>User Login</h1>
    <form id="loginform" name="loginform" method="post" action="index.html">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="txtfield" tabindex="1">

      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="txtfield" tabindex="2">

      <div class="center"><input type="submit" name="loginbtn" id="loginbtn" class="flatbtn-blu hidemodal" value="Log In" tabindex="3"></div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Drop Down menu::

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control" id="count">
     <option value="0" selected="selected">Select Variable</option>
     <option value="a">a </option>
     <option value="b">b </option>
     <option value="c">c </option>
</select>
```

Java Script ::

```
$('#count).change(function() {

                document.getElementById('loginmodal').click();
                $('#modaltrigger').leanModal({ top: 110, overlay: 0.45, closeButton: ".hidemodal" });


                  });
```

but its not working for me .Can some one help me into this?

Comment: Are errors thrown? Code shown has obvious syntax problem as witnessed by the code highlighting. Is code wrapped in a `document.ready` handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this answer

[jQuery get value of select onChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179406/jquery-get-value-of-select-onchange)

and this on

[How to open a Bootstrap modal window using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183630/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-window-using-jquery)

it should be something like this:

```
$('#count').change(function()
{
    if (this.value == 'c')
    {
         $('#loginmodal').modal('show');
    }
});
```