# Trigger bootstrap modal with PHP (not via modal button)

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a HTML form completed by the user and then submitted via the Post action into a PHP script. It validates the data and uploads the info to a DB. All good. at the end of the PHP script I want to open a bootstrap modal. i.e. without the user clicking another button to launch it. The modal I have works fine if you use the modal button like so

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

I've tried a few ways to get it to run in the PHP script, this looking like the most promising:

```
echo '<script>$("#myModal").modal({show: true});</script>';
```

But no luck. I'm a complete noob when it comes to JS!

Comment: You want to open a modal where you can submit data through form ? Or, you want success/failure message in modal after submitting ?

Comment: After the script is finished I just want the modal box to popup. The simple version is, how do I open a modal box from a PHP script?

Answer (score 0):

Few functions of bootstrap modal.

```
$('#myModal').modal('toggle');
$('#myModal').modal('show');
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

Change this

```
$('#myModal').modal({show: 'false'});
```

To

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

For more info, click [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183630/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-window-using-jquery)

Comment: If you look my example says ``modal({show: true})`` . I've tried the example you suggested also.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I should have just looked a bit harder. The answer is just that you need to wrap jquery in a function when calling from PHP.

```
jQuery(function(){
    //Your Code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use javacript window load function to trigger button and call modal without clicking the button and button can bi hidden also.
Here is your PHP code:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> $(window).load(function(){ $('#myModal').modal('show'); }); </script>";
```

You can use some 'if' conditions to determine when trigger will be triggered.