# Create jquery modal by clicking on table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am beginner in jquery,
I have table which contains one column like no of employees (total no of employee in department) when user clicks on it it should display list of employees in jquery modal `(like EmpA,EmpB,EmpC)` when clicking on specific `employee (EmpA)` should display details of that `EmpA` .

Comment: have you gone through Jqueryui Documentation for modal window?

Comment: Yes I have gone through jqueryui documentation but I didn't find solutions

Comment: Are you using bootstrap with mvc?

Comment: is this what you want http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Yes bootstrap with mvc

Comment: you dont need bootstrap to do so

Comment: Hi akshay I want to open that dialog on click of table cell which contains list by clicking on specific item from list should open details of item

Comment: `$('#table-cell-id').dialog(options);` would work. where in options you must have a look at the documentation link provided at the bottom of the page that I shared the link for

Comment: Hi Akshay I had tried as you described but it didn't work will will you explain In brief.

Answer (score 0):

You have a huge question. It is not just a question, it is an application. I can help you get started by showing you how you can (a) use a modal, (b) open/close the modal, and (c) stick stuff into the modal. After that, you must experiment / work with it before asking another question. Fair enough?

For the modal, you have three choices:

(1) You can write your own modal. Not very difficult, but if you are already using another system that includes modals, you should use that.

(2) You can use jQueryUI -- but this is not the same as jQuery. It is an enhancement/add-on to jQuery, the same as Bootstrap is. jQueryUI includes a modal dialog - but so does Bootstrap.

(3) Since you are already using Bootstrap, and since Bootstrap includes a cool modal system, you can -- and should -- use the Bootstrap modal system. It is quite easy.

[Here is a link](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp) to how the Bootstrap modal system works.

In your case, you might wish to use [the jQuery/javascript method of opening/closing the modal.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13183713/1447509) This allows you to decide programmatically when to open the modal.

You also need to populate the modal with new data. Notice that the Bootstrap modal basically looks like this:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div>This is the body of the modal. This is where your data goes (HTML table, values, etc).</div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Notice the class called `modal-body`. If you inject new HTML code in there using the jQuery `.html()` method, you can change what is inside the modal dialog.

```js
$('#mybutt').click(function(){
    var newstuff = '\
      <div id="newstuff">\
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/400/150" /><br>\
        <h1>This is an example</h1>\
        <h3>Of some new stuff in the modal</h3>\
        <button id="nutherbutt">Click me next</button>\
      </div>\
    ';
    $('.modal-body').html(newstuff);  
});

$(document).on('click', '#nutherbutt', function(){
  //You must use .on() to trap events for injected tags
  alert('you clicked me');
  $('#myModal').modal('hide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>



<!-- - - - - -  Modal  - - - - - -  -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        <button id="mybutt">Click Me!</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the libraries are included; jquery, bootstrap.css, bootstrap.js

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

<!-- trigger modal -->
<td>
  Total
</td>
<td>
  <a href=""  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">4 emplyees</a>
</td>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">List of emplyees</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <ul>
           <li>Emp 1</li>
           <li>Emp 2</li>
           <li>Emp 3</li>
           <li>Emp 4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```