# CakePHP use ajax to load modal content

Tags: ajax, cakephp, modal-dialog

I want to add a notification box on my navigation bar. so  when I click on a new notification div I want to show my modal with my notification text and here I used the following ajax function but it can't show me the modal text .

```
function viewPost(IDnotif){
  var notifId = IDnotif;

  var data = "id="+ notifId;
       $.ajax({
             type: "post",  // Request method: post, get
             url: base_url + "/icicpermis/notifications/getNotification/"+notifId,
             data: data,
             success: function(response) { 

                        document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";

                        document.getElementById("titre").text('New notification ');

                           },
                           error:function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                  alert(textStatus);
                           }
          });
          return false;
}

 </script>
```

and that's my modal :

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content" id="content">
    <span class="close">x</span>

    <p id='titre'>Nouvelle notification  </p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: @Poonam There is no error in the console

Comment: And why this `return false;` after ajax call?

Comment: @Poonam When I removed it i got the following error Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).text is not a function(…) so I dont know how can I set the content text

Comment: @Poonam Still got the same error Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).html is not a function(…)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128139/discussion-between-poonam-and-afaf).

Comment: Use `document.getElementById("titre").innerHTML = "New notification";`

Comment: Simple google search gives [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183630/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-window-using-jquery). Consider learning jquery a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript `.text()` will not work. You have to change the `html` of `#titre`

So, In javascript use `innerHTML`,

```
document.getElementById("titre").innerHTML = "New notification";
```

You can use jQuery too

```
$('#titre').html('New notification');
```

Remove `return false;` after ajax call because it will hide the errors.