# open modal in another link

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can I open a modal in another link using this link?

```
<a href="process.php&data=3" data-toggle="modal"data-target="#modal-view">
 link                         
</a>
```

And in process.php have this modal and I want to get data from that link.

```
 <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <?php $data=$_GET[data]; echo $data; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: not able to get your question. please elaborate

Comment: try answer I posted. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

Add id to a tag

```
<a id="myLink" href="process.php&data=3" data-toggle="modal"data-target="#modal-view">
 link                         
</a>
```

Add id to div tag

```
 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <?php $data=$_GET[data]; echo $data; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

And apply click event on your link and load your content remotely,

```
$('a#myLink').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#myModal').modal('show').find('.modal-body').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would just need to run the javascript function to load a modal when the page loads.

This post has some good ways to do this: [How to open a Bootstrap modal window using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183630/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-window-using-jquery)

In short, something like this would be needed in your javascript in the other page to open the modal when the page loads:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

You may need to give your modal an ID attribute so that it could be easily referenced uniquely.