# how to call javascript modal without button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following button:

```
<button data-toggle="tk-modal-demo" data-modal-options="slide-left" data-dialog-options="sidebar sidebar-size-3 sidebar-size-xs-1 sidebar-offset-0 left" class="btn btn-primary">Slide left</button>
```

Which calls this modal:

```
<script id="tk-modal-demo" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
              <div class="modal fade">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                  <div class="v-cell">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A aperiam atque consequuntur dolore fugiat fugit hic in ipsam iure magnam maxime quaerat, quam qui repellat repellendus temporibus vel vitae voluptate!
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </script>
```

How can I popup to modal when the page loads instead of when the button is pressed? In other words, what javascript do i call?

Something like `tk-modal-demo()` ?

Comment: @CrisMVP3200 That is my question, how do I do that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is in the bootstrap documentation

Comment: @charlietfl I'm a bootstrap noob.  That's why I am asking the question for myself and others in the future.  SO is the new documentation.

Comment: Call 'show' on load https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183630/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-window-using-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a Bootstrap modal window using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183630/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-window-using-jquery)

Comment: Please, at least do the basic Googling before writing a question.

Comment: Asking here before reading the docs is just being completely lazy

Comment: I didn't even know this was a bootstrap widget.  I inherited the code.  You guys are wound a little tight today.

Comment: No not at all.... just like most libraries it is well documented

Comment: @charlietfl do you want to talk about this offline, it sounds like there is something more going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either add the classes `show` and `in` to the HTML, as in:

```
<div class="modal fade show in">
```

Or you can invoke the 'show' method programmatically

```
$(".modal").modal("show");
```

**See running demo below**

```js
$(function() {
  /* Or you can invoke the 'show' method programmatically */
  //$(".modal").modal("show");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>content</div>

<!-- Either add the classes 'show' and 'in' to the HTML -->
<div class="modal fade show in">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="v-cell">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A aperiam atque consequuntur dolore fugiat fugit hic in ipsam iure magnam maxime quaerat, quam qui repellat repellendus temporibus vel vitae voluptate!
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to add the `show` class to your modal:

```
<script id="tk-modal-demo" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="modal show fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="v-cell">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                 <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A aperiam atque consequuntur dolore fugiat fugit hic in ipsam iure magnam maxime quaerat, quam qui repellat repellendus temporibus vel vitae voluptate!
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can click the button using Javascript:

```
document.querySelector('button[data-toggle="tk-modal-demo"]').click()
```

But I highly suggest reading the documentation of the modal, there must be a function to show/hide. For example; if it's a Bootstrap modal, you can show it like this:

```
$('#tk-modal-demo').modal('show');
```

---

To make the call on page load:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // CODE GOES HERE
});
```

Or if you use jQuery:

```
$(window).on('load',function() {
  // CODE GOES HERE
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in react typescript project

```
document.querySelector('button[data-toggle="leadModal"]').click()
```

but you need button with all the required attributes

```
<button className="main-btn" data-bs-toggle="modal"
     data-bs-target="#leadModal" onClick={openModal}>
     Download Brochure
</button>
```

Comment: This really just copies one of the other answers, right?