# call bootstrap modal dialog through script function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In my html page, now I open modal dialog in this way

Modal Call button

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editBox" href="file.php?id=<?php echo $obj->id;?>">
```

The following html code in page

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editBox" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          //Content Will show Here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is file.php

```
<?php
$Id = $_GET["id"];
?>
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title"><center>Heading</center></h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    //Show records fetched from database against $Id
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

What if I need to call the modal through script function ?

I have this

```
eventClick: function (result) {

   // call the dialog passing $id
})
```

EDIT

I need to pass $id value

Now I call the dialog with

```
href="file.php?id=<?php echo $obj->id;?>"
```

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a Bootstrap modal window using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183630/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-window-using-jquery)

Comment: I need to pass $id value!

Comment: Not sure that warranted an !, but check the documentation link provided.  `$('#editBox').modal({remote: url + "?id=" + id, show:true})` or just use ajax to load the content.

Comment: yeeeeeeesss :)) Thanks a lot..... !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the url to load when opening the modal with the `remote` option:

```
$('#editBox').modal({
    remote: url + "?id=" + id, 
    show: true
});
```

The current recommendation is to use ajax to load the content rather than use the `remote:` option - this will be removed in later versions of bootstrap.

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-javascript