# .modal('show'); - not showing modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

im trying to show a modal that will show textboxes with values from the table i displayed. im using this code to trigger the modal: `$('#updatemodal').modal('show');` but it's not working.

this is the script for transferring the table contents to the modal and displaying the modal as well:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click','.edit_data',function(){  
       var awardee_id = $(this).attr("uawardeeid");  
       $.ajax({  
            url:"fetchawardees.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{awardee_id:awardee_id},  
            dataType:"json",  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('#updatemodal').modal('show');
                 $('#uawardeeid').val(data.awardee_id);   
                 $('#uawardeename').val(data.awardee_name);   
                 $('#uawardeeaddress').val(data.awardee_address);   
                 $('#uawardeecontact').val(data.awardee_contact_info);   
                 $('#uaward').val(data.award_id);   
                 $('#ucategory').val(data.category_id);   
                 $('#uregion').val(data.region_id);   
                 $('#uprovince').val(data.province_id);   
                 $('#uimage').val(data.awardee_img);   

            }  
       });  
  });
```

this is the code for the modal contents:

```
            <form class="form-horizontal" id="updateform" name="updateform" action="phpawardee.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="modal fade in" tabindex="" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false"  name="updatemodal" id="updatemodal">   
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" >
                <div class="modal-content" >
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Awardee</h4>
                    </div>
        <div class="modal-body">  

                <div class="panel-body">
                          <input id="uawardeeid" name="uawardeeid" type="text" class="form-control">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <!-- Name input--> 
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="name">Awardee Name</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <input id="uawardeename" name="uawardeename" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Address body -->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="message">Address</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <textarea class="form-control resize_vertical" id="uawardeeaddress" name="uawardeeaddress" placeholder="" rows="4"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Contact info input-->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="name">Contact Info.</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <input id="uawardeecontact" name="uawardeecontact" type="number" placeholder="" class="form-control" ></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Level of Award input-->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="email">Level of Award</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <select id="uaward" name="uaward" class="form-control">
                                                <option>Select</option>
                                                    <?php
                                                        $res=mysqli_query($db, "select * from tbl_award_level");
                                                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                                                        {
                                                    ?>
                                                 <option value="<?php echo $row["award_id"]?>"><?php echo $row["award_name"]; ?></option>
                                                    <?php
                                                        }
                                                    ?>
                                            </select></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- Store Category-->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="email">Store Category</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <select id="ucategory" name="ucategory" class="form-control">
                                                <option>Select</option>
                                                    <?php
                                                       $res=mysqli_query($db, "select * from tbl_store_category");
                                                     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                                                       {
                                                    ?>
                                                <option value="<?php echo $row["category_id"]?>">
                                                    <?php echo $row["category_name"]; ?></option>
                                                    <?php
                                                            }
                                                    ?>
                                            </select></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--Region-->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Region</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <select id="uregion" name="uregion" class="form-control" onChange="change_region2()">
                                                <option>Select</option>
                                                    <?php
                                                        $res=mysqli_query($db, "select * from tbl_region");
                                                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
                                                            {
                                                    ?>
                                                <option value="<?php echo $row["region_id"]?>">
                                                    <?php echo $row["region_name"]; ?></option>
                                                    <?php
                                                            }
                                                    ?>
                                            </select></div>
                                    </div>
                                     <!-- Province-->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Province</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <select id="uprovince" name="uprovince" class="form-control">
                                                <option>Select</option>
                                                <option></option>

                                            </select></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--File Upload-->
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="name">Choose Photo</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <div class="fileinput fileinput-new input-group" data-provides="fileinput">
                                                <div class="form-control" data-trigger="fileinput" >
                                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file fileinput-exists"></i>
                                                    <span class="fileinput-filename"></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <span class="input-group-addon btn btn-default btn-file">
                                                    <span class="fileinput-new">Select file</span>
                                                    <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span>
                                                    <input type="file" name="uimage" ></span>
                                                <a href="#" class="input-group-addon btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>

                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="updatebutton" name="updatebutton">Update</button>
                            </div>
                                    <!-- Form actions -->
                                </fieldset>

                        </div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

and here is the code of the button i should click to show the modal:

```
<a name="edit" value="Edit" data-toggle="modal" id="<?php echo $awardee["awardee_id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-md btn-primary edit_data" >Edit</a>
```

Comment: Refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183630/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-window-using-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a Bootstrap modal window using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183630/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-window-using-jquery)

Comment: I tried the solution from the link you commented, but it's still not working.

Comment: Is ajax success is true?

Comment: I don't know. Everytime I click the button, nothing's showing, yet there is no error. . @Rp9

Comment: put a console log inside success and check

Comment: with the php inline can't test it on jsfiddle but one thing to check is if the id has a duplicate. Try calling it on the console and also viewing the `.html()` to be sure you got the right one and also calling modal again on the console. Also trivial to ask but any errors on the console?

Comment: @Zoo   waht u want ??  on EDIT button click modal open????

Comment: @MohitKumar yes

Comment: @Zoo    then u add data-target="#updatemodal" & let me know.

Comment: @zoo check in console, I think you are not getting JSON Object from your AJAX Call.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your code.

you have used

```
var awardee_id = $(this).attr("uawardeeid");
```

But in your button you are not mentioning "uawardeeid".

```
<a name="edit" value="Edit" data-toggle="modal" id="<?php echo $awardee["awardee_id"]; ?>" class="btn btn-md btn-primary edit_data" >Edit</a>
```

In your jQuery replace

```
var awardee_id = $(this).attr("id");
```

Hope it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Please mark answer approved if it helped. Thanks @zoo

Answer (score 0):

Open the developers tools (F12) and go to Network tab.
There when you press the button you should see the POST you made and can check the params you sent and the response that your AJAX got.

Check if the POST is correct as you expected it.
Its is probably an error in your PHP controller 'fetchawardees.php'.