# Updating data in mysql database with bootstrap modal and AJAX in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to update user details in mysql database using bootstrap modal form without page refresh but when i press the edit button, the modal is not opening and nothing happens.

This is my edit button. Is there any problem with my coding or syntax ?

```
   <button type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit btn btn-sm btn-default edit_user " id="'.$row["uID"].'" name="edit""></button>
```

**This is my add user modal.**

```
<!-- Add user modal -->
<div id="add_user_Modal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Add New User/Admin</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="post" id="add_user_form">
                <label>Enter Employee ID</label>
                <input type="text" name="user_id" id="user_id" class="form-control" required/>
                <br />
                <label>Enter Employee Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" required/>
                <br />
                <label>Enter Employee Email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" required/>
                <br />
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" required/>
                <br />
                <label>Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" class="form-control" required/>
                <br />
                <label>Account Type</label>
                <select name="account" id="account" class="form-control">
                    <option value="Guest">Guest</option>
                    <option value="Admin">Admin</option>

                </select>
                <br />
<input type="hidden" name="uid" id="uid" />
                <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-success" />

            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the java script for ajax, the AJAX error were 
"Requested JSON parse failed."

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    //add
    $('#add_user_form').on("submit", function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({

                url:"add_user.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:$('#add_user_form').serialize(),
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $('#insert').val("Inserting");
                },
                success:function(data){
                    alert("succees")
                    $('#add_user_form')[0].reset();
                    $('#add_user_Modal').modal('hide');
                    $('#datatable-buttons').html(data);
                },

        });
    });


$(document).on('click', '.edit_user', function(){
        var uid = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch_user_details.php",
            method:"POST",
            data: {uid:uid},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data),

                $('#username').val(data.username);
                $('#email').val(data.email);
                $('#password').val(data.password);
                $('#account').val(data.account);
                $('#user_id').val(data.user_id);
                $('#insert').val("Update");
                $('#add_user_Modal').modal('show');
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, exception) {

                var msg = '';
                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                    msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                    msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                    msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                    msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                    msg = 'Time out error.';
                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                    msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                } else {
                    msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                }
                $('#post').html(msg);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your are referencing the wrong Id. This might be a possible duplicate of [13183630](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183630)

Comment: do you mean the ajax data below ?

Comment: No. I was referring to the edit button in your code.

Answer (score 0):

you button should be like this

```
<button type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit btn btn-sm btn-default 
edit_user " id="'.$row["uID"].'" name="edit" data-toggle="modal" data- target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
```

Comment: but the success function below will show the modal right ?

Comment: ya, i hope. ;))