# MVC show modal if form submit is valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

Good day! I want to create a modal that pops-up when the user clicks the submit button only if the form is valid just like [this](http://www.primaryobjects.com/2012/03/21/creating-a-jquery-modal-confirmation-dialog-when-submitting-a-form/). The form validation works perfectly after click but when the form is valid, nothing happens to the form and the modal doesn't pop-up.

I have tried the solutions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183630/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-window-using-jquery) such as

```
$('#myModal').modal("show");
$('#myModal').dialog('open');
$('#myModal').modal();
$('#myModal').show();
$('#myModal').modal('toggle');
```

but still not popping up.

**VIEW**

```
<div class="col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-12">
 @using (Html.BeginForm("CedulaModule", "ApplicationForm", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "contactForm", name = "contactForm" }))
{
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ApplicationCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ApplicationCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = @ViewBag.iAppFrmDet, @readonly = "readonly" } })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Firstname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Firstname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Firstname) } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Firstname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MiddleInitial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.MiddleInitial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.MiddleInitial) } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MiddleInitial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Surname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Surname) } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" id="validate" class="btn btn-default"/>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**MODAL**

```
<div id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            Confirm Submit
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" class="close">×</button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
                    @Html.Partial("CedulaPartial")
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#contactForm').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).valid()) {
        $('#myModal').modal("show");
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you put references of `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.min.js` on your view?

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution I am using the default bootstrap css of MVC

Comment: Getting any console error?

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution I get no error. Nothing happens after clicking the button but when no data was entered, validation works

Answer (score 2):

If your form is valid save this information in any TempData and check this var on form load if data flag is exist then show your modal.

Add TempData in control post action.

```
TempData[“modalValid”]=true;
```

On form load using JavaScript.

```
$(document)ready(function (){
 If(@TempData[“modalValid””]==true)
      //display your modal
      //set null in TempData
});
```

This code is not tested this is only for your reference.

Comment: Tried this but still the modal doesn't pop-up

Comment: Share console  error. Check Modal reference is loading or not .

Comment: No error is showing when I run the system. As soon as the button was clicked, nothing happens but when there is a validation error, the code works

Comment: I noticed that this part of code, 'if ($(this).valid()) {
        $('#myModal').modal("show");
    }' doesn't work. When I include 'e.preventDefaul();' it won't trigger, same with removing the 'e.preventDefault();'

Comment: Check Point : Run your program and copy show modal code in console and check modal is display or not? Check form valid function value in console this is true or not?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

After running into this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280634/trigger-modal-if-form-valid-using-jquery). I was able to make the code also work. Unfortunately, it was the class that was causing me error. As soon as I removed it, my code also worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The e.preventDefault() call is preventing the submit every time. Even when the form is valid. Try using a flag "confirmed" to make sure the e.preventDefault() is only called before the modal has been shown.

```js
var confirmed = false;
function SubmitConfirmfunction() {

    confirmed = false;
    $("#contactForm").submit();

}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#contactForm').submit(function (e) {
    
        if (confirmed == false) {
            if ($(this).valid()) {
                confirmed = true;
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#myModal').modal("show");
            }
        }
    });
});
```