# click a link to bring up modal

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

Hopefully someone here can help.

I am trying to click on "find the nearest supplier to you" to bring up a modal.

The info comes from a database and lists them perfectly. However only the first "Find the nearest supplier to you" link when clicked bring up the modal but none of the others.

Can't seem to figure out what I have missed?

Thanks in advance.

```
<tbody>

<?php while ($row=$read->fetch_assoc()) { ?>

    <tr class="info">
        <td><img src="uploads/<?php echo  $row['images']; ?>"</td>
        <td><?php echo  $row['manu'], $row['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo  $row['address'];   ?></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo  $row['website'];   ?>" target=_blank> Website </a></td>        
        <td><button id="modalBtn" class="button">Find the Nearest Supplier to you</button></td>
            <div id="simpleModal" class="modal">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <span class="closeBtn">&times;</span>
                        <p>I am a modal.......</p>
                </div>
            </div>                       
    </tr>

<?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: it looks like you have duplicate IDs, if you output this HTML in a loop

Comment: try `<button id="modalBtn-<?= $row['id'] ?>"` and `<div id="simpleModal-<?= $row['id'] ?>"`

Comment: you forgot to add data-toggle.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183630/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-window-using-jquery

Comment: you are using duplicate id and this is the expected behaviour in this situation. Use a class instead

Comment: Hi Alex, that did not work.  It gave me the modals showing and then the list without the "nearest supplier link, just the button