# Modal won't show programmatically

Tags: ajax, laravel, core-ui

I have a button which shows a modal when clicked.

The button is:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary assignRole" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#assignRole">
        New
    </button>
```

and the modal is:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="assignRole" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Assign New Client Role to Employee</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-group">
            </form>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">
               <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span> Close
               </button>
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add-role-to-user" data-dismiss="modal">
               <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-check'></span> Add
               </button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

These work fine when the button is clicked manually but I would like the modal to show on error.

I am using the following code:

```
error: function(errors){
                setTimeout(function (){
                    $(".assignRole").click();
                    toastr.error('Validation error!', errors.responseJSON.message, {timeOut: 5000});
                }, 500);
        }
```

Could someone please point out where I am going wrong. I am using coreui admin template and chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of triggering the click on the button, you can try this approach to show your modal:

```
$('#assignRole').modal('show');
```

Comment: Can you open the developer console and share what's the error that you get?

Comment: edit:1546 Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at Object.error (edit:1546)
    at fire (jquery-2.2.4.js:3187)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery-2.2.4.js:3317)
    at done (jquery-2.2.4.js:8759)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.2.4.js:9123)

Comment: this error comes from somewhere else in the code my friend so you need to figure that out first, as that's what blocks the execution on the other part later.

Comment: I have sorted the error out and I am now getting "422 (Unprocessable Entity)" in the console. The toast shows though.

Comment: that means that your ajax request is still not correct as the data you are passing is wrong. You can find many answers for the 422 error. But the modal should appear depends on which one you are using, is it the button click or the `modal('show')` call?

Answer (score 0):

It has finally worked after adding `jQuery.noConflict();` before                     `$('#assignRole').modal('show');`.

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34870788/10123373).