# How to make an html <a> tag run automatically

Tags: javascript, html

```html
 <div class="modal fade" id="logoutModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ready to Leave?</h5>
          <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">Username or Password is incorrect.</div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a class="btn btn-primary" href="login.html">Ok</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

so i have this tag that is currently a button. When i click on this button it runs a display message.

How can i make this tag to automatically run when the page opens or reloads.

```html
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logoutModal">Logout</a>;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a Bootstrap modal window using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183630/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-window-using-jquery)  assume you are using bootstrap model

Comment: i dont want to click on anything, i want it to run without clicking anything

Answer (score 1):

The click() method execute a click on an element as if the user manually clicked on it.

Add id on your code:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#logoutModal" id="example">Logout</a>
```

And use js:

```
document.getElementById('example').click();
```

Comment: i want to do it without clicking i pasted the modal code

Comment: This is without clicking (js simulate as if the user click on the link).

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger after the page is loaded

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown-item").trigger( "click" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment above...

> I am trying to do a form where if the user enters wrong credentials
>   the modal will pop up.

...maybe this will help. If not, then you need to clarify what you're trying to do in your question.

In the snippet below, I have a login form. When the wrong credentials are entered, the modal appears.

```js
$("#login").click(function () {
    // Here you would do your check for correct credentials
    // Obviously you wouldn't want to do this in JS in production
    // I'm assuming there would be an AJAX request here that would validate the user's credentials
    // If valid, proceed. If not, call the modal.
    if ($(username).val() !== "blah" || $(password).val() !== "blah") {
   // Username or password incorrect, show modal
    $("#modal").modal();
  } else {
   alert("Login successful!");
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


Username: <input id="username" type="text" />
Password: <input id="password" type="password" />
<button type="button" id="login" class="btn btn-info">Login</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Ready to Leave?</h5>
        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">Username or Password is incorrect.</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Try again</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically, anytime you want the modal to appear automatically (i.e., without clicking on anything), just call it like this:

```
$("#idOfModal").modal();
```

If you want to programmatically hide or dismiss the modal, you can do that by passing `hide` to the `modal` function:

```
$("#idOfModal').modal("hide");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`$("#logoutModal").modal('show')`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/#modalshow)
on [`$(document).ready(() => ...)`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myModal").modal('show');
});
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#logOut").modal('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="logOut" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure you want to Logout?</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger float-right">Yes</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```