# load dynamic data from remote url into a bootstrap modal pop up

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, popup, bootstrap-modal

I have the following href link

```
<a href="{$data.base_url}find_dates.html"  data-toggle="modal" style="color:#fff;" class="modal-ajax">Click Here to View data</a>
```

and the pop is showing on page reload, but I want to show it only on click.

```
$('.modal-ajax').modal();
```

Now the page is redirect into url. I want to show the pop up

I didnt wrote any js code. i tried this now

```
$('a').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $('.modal-ajax').modal();
    return true; 
} );
```

but it raises $('.modal-ajax').modal(); is not a function error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a Bootstrap modal window using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183630/how-to-open-a-bootstrap-modal-window-using-jquery)

Comment: No. its differnt. it was working before but now something happened... i didnt wrote any javascript cod

Comment: you want to open modal on anchor click , So you need to use ID or class of the Modal i.e $("#modalID") or $(".ModalClass") .Try this way

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<a href="#" data-id="{$data.base_url}find_dates.html"  data-toggle="modal" style="color:#fff;" class="modal-ajax">Click Here to View data</a>


$('.modal-ajax').on('click', function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('data-id');
    //place this value wherever you want in modal.
    $('#openModal').show();
});
```

Comment: sorry here the case is differnt

Comment: Ok, If you don't want to redirect, may I know the purpose of showing the url in href?

Comment: to load that url data into pop up is what i m tdoing

Comment: @SherinReynold, please check the answer now

Comment: i didnt have any openModal

Comment: @SherinReynold, change that to your modal id.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: http://url error

Answer (score 0):

You could simply put a comment on the javascript code that trigger the modal :

```
// $('.modal-ajax').modal();
```

Then add a click event listener for the element you wish to be clicked :

```
$('a.modal-ajax').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.modal-ajax').modal();
});
```

Comment: sorry the page is redirecting before showing pop up

Comment: I've changed my answer, please check again

Comment: still redirecting. pls help

Comment: Did the page still redirecting **after** you click the link?

Comment: hi sir   i wrote somethinh like this $('.modal-ajax').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.modal-ajax').modal();
    return true
});

Comment: but it shows pop up only on first time. but on second time i shows ....modal() is not a function