# Set each different color in the event box with full calendar function

Tags: jquery, colors, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have a problem setting the color in each event box in the full calendar function. Currently, I just can set in the fc-daygrid-event-dot. May I know how to set the background color in each event box?

Below is my coding:

```html
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // titleFormat: 'MMMM D, YYYY' 
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      },
      initialDate: '2021-04-25',
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      selectable: true,
      selectMirror: true,
      
      
      select: function(arg) {
      $('#createEventModal #startTime').val(arg.start);
      $('#createEventModal #endTime').val(arg.end);
      $('#createEventModal #when').text(arg.start);
      $('#createEventModal').modal('toggle');
    },
      eventClick: function(arg) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this event?')) {
          arg.event.remove()
        }
      },
      editable: true,
      dayMaxEvents: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: <?php echo json_encode($myArray); ?>
    });
    calendar.render();   
  });
```

This is my `json_encode($myArray);` data:

```html
[{"title":"All Day Event","start":"2016-01-01 00:00:00","color":"#40E0D0"},{"title":"Long Event","start":"2016-01-07 00:00:00","color":"#FF0000"},{"title":"Repeating Event","start":"2016-01-09 16:00:00","color":"#0071c5"},{"title":"Conference","start":"2016-01-11 00:00:00","color":"#40E0D0"},{"title":"Meeting","start":"2016-01-12 10:30:00","color":"#000"},{"title":"Lunch","start":"2016-01-12 12:00:00","color":"#0071c5"},{"title":"Happy Hour","start":"2016-01-12 17:30:00","color":"#0071c5"},{"title":"Dinner","start":"2016-01-12 20:00:00","color":"#0071c5"},{"title":"Birthday Party","start":"2016-01-14 07:00:00","color":"#FFD700"},{"title":"Double click to change","start":"2016-01-28 00:00:00","color":"#008000"},{"title":"13245132","start":"2021-03-31 00:00:00","color":"undefin"},{"title":"asfsa","start":"2021-04-01 00:00:00","color":"undefin"},{"title":"52115","start":"2021-04-01 00:00:00","color":"undefin"},{"title":"624","start":"2021-04-01 00:00:00","color":"undefin"},{"title":"512","start":"2021-04-04 00:00:00","color":"#FF0000"},{"title":"21512","start":"2021-04-06 00:00:00","color":"#FF0000"},{"title":"236234","start":"2021-04-07 00:00:00","color":"#FF0000"},{"title":"3521","start":"2021-04-03 00:00:00","color":"#00FF00"},{"title":"HHH","start":"2021-04-02 00:00:00","color":"#FFFF00"},{"title":"test","start":"2021-03-30 00:00:00","color":"#378006"},{"title":"asfsa","start":"2021-03-28 00:00:00","color":"#378006"},{"title":"ok","start":"2021-03-29 00:00:00","color":"#378006"},{"title":"ok","start":"2021-04-01 00:00:00","color":"#378006"},{"title":"ok","start":"2021-03-31 00:00:00","color":"#378006"},{"title":"555","start":"2021-04-16 00:00:00","color":"#378006"},{"title":"asfsa","start":"2021-03-28 00:00:00","color":"#FF0000"}]
```

Now my result like below the picture, each color just can show in the dot:

[image: output1]

Actually, I want the expected result like below the sample picture:

[image: output2]

What I've tried：
i）I have tried to change color to background-color in the `json_encode($myArray);` data, but still cannot work.

Swati result:

[image: output 3]

[image: output 5]

Comment: HI, which version of fullcalender are you using ?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialize-globals
version 5.6.0 I think this version

Comment: @Swati Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [eventDidMount](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks) event inside this you can use `.each` loop to iterate through your json array and then we need to get the `td` where events are added .

Now , if you look dynamically generated `td` you will find `data-date` attribute so use this attribute then there can two or more event on same date so you can use `title` key from your json array and check this value is there inside `fc-event-title` div or not lastly use `.closest(".fc-daygrid-event-harness")` and change back-ground color of that div.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//suppose this is array
var arrays = [{
  "title": "All Day Event",
  "start": "2016-01-01 00:00:00",
  "color": "#40E0D0"
}, {
  "title": "Long Event",
  "start": "2016-01-07 00:00:00",
  "color": "#FF0000"
}, {
  "title": "Repeating Event",
  "start": "2016-01-09 16:00:00",
  "color": "#0071c5"
}, {
  "title": "Conference",
  "start": "2016-01-11 00:00:00",
  "color": "#40E0D0"
}, {
  "title": "Meeting",
  "start": "2016-01-12 10:30:00",
  "color": "#000"
}, {
  "title": "Lunch",
  "start": "2016-01-12 12:00:00",
  "color": "#0071c5"
}, {
  "title": "Happy Hour",
  "start": "2016-01-12 17:30:00",
  "color": "#0071c5"
}, {
  "title": "Dinner",
  "start": "2016-01-12 20:00:00",
  "color": "#0071c5"
}, {
  "title": "Birthday Party",
  "start": "2016-01-14 07:00:00",
  "color": "#FFD700"
}, {
  "title": "Double click to change",
  "start": "2016-01-28 00:00:00",
  "color": "#008000"
}, {
  "title": "512",
  "start": "2021-04-04 00:00:00",
  "color": "#FF0000"
}, {
  "title": "21512",
  "start": "2021-04-06 00:00:00",
  "color": "#FF0000"
}, {
  "title": "236234",
  "start": "2021-04-07 00:00:00",
  "color": "#FF0000"
}, {
  "title": "3521",
  "start": "2021-04-03 00:00:00",
  "color": "#00FF00"
}, {
  "title": "HHH",
  "start": "2021-04-02 00:00:00",
  "color": "#FFFF00"
}, {
  "title": "test",
  "start": "2021-03-30 00:00:00",
  "color": "#378006"
}, {
  "title": "43",
  "start": "2021-03-28 00:00:00",
  "color": "#378006"
}, {
  "title": "ok",
  "start": "2021-03-29 00:00:00",
  "color": "#378006"
}, {
  "title": "o2k",
  "start": "2021-04-01 00:00:00",
  "color": "#378006"
}, {
  "title": "ok3",
  "start": "2021-03-31 00:00:00",
  "color": "#378006"
}, {
  "title": "5553",
  "start": "2021-04-16 00:00:00",
  "color": "#378006"
}, {
  "title": "asfsa",
  "start": "2021-03-28 00:00:00",
  "color": "#FF0000"
}]

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
    },
    initialDate: '2021-04-25',
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    selectable: true,
    selectMirror: true,
    eventDidMount: function(view) {
      //loop through json array
      $(arrays).each(function(i, val) {
        //find td->check if the title has same value-> get closest daygird ..change color there
        $("td[data-date=" + moment(val.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD") + "] .fc-event-title:contains(" + val.title + ")").closest(".fc-daygrid-event-harness").css("background-color", val.color);
      })
    },
    select: function(arg) {
      $('#createEventModal #startTime').val(arg.start);
      $('#createEventModal #endTime').val(arg.end);
      $('#createEventModal #when').text(arg.start);
      $('#createEventModal').modal('toggle');
    },
    eventClick: function(arg) {
      if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this event?')) {
        arg.event.remove()
      }
    },
    editable: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true,
    events: arrays //pass array here
  });

  calendar.render();


});
```

```css
.fc-event-title {
  color: white
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.6.0/main.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.6.0/main.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the result cannot change all background color, you can check my updated question

Comment: from where that blue color coming :P in your result i am not seeing them in my code ?

Comment: If you see its setting color correctly but , that blue color is overrriding that . Can you make runnable code ? Because i am seeing that behaviour on my end so i have look in your code to find exact reason.

Comment: Thanks. I think is script problem. How to change word become white color?

Comment: use css `.fc-event-title { color :white }` . Also , for previous issue check if after changing `.closest(".fc-daygrid-event-harness")` to `.closest(".fc-event")` works .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231692/discussion-between-swati-and-pi-network-crytocurrency).

Comment: I have another question same as this question. If you have time, you see can help me or not. Thanks.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67302723/event-click-show-the-selected-data-with-fullcalendar-function

Answer (score 2):

Your data contains a "color" key for each event.
To achieve what you need you could set the "backgroundColor" key instead, which sets the color of the event. Please the the documentation here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object

```
    {[{"title":"All Day Event","backgroundColor": "yellow", "start":"2016-01-01 00:00:00","color":"#40E0D0"}...]
```

For a working example, please visit [working example](https://codepen.io/ormasoftchile/pen/NWdmYGo)