# How to open modal window when logging

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am carrying out a new functionality with my login and it is that I require that when entering your session, that is, after entering with your username and password, a modal window is loaded immediately, I attach below a small code fragment with which I am making my login:

```js
function EnterLogin(){
    if($('#username').val() != '' && $('#password').val() != '') 
    {                 
        $('.load').show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: {
              param: 1,
              username: $('#username').val(),
              password: $('#password').val()
            },
            url: "test.php",
           dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
                $('.load').hide();
                if(data.length){
                    for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                        if(data[i]['valido'] == 1){
                         $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            async: false,
                            data: {
                              param: 3,
                              username: $('#username').val()
                            },
                            url: "test.php",
                            dataType: 'JSON',
                            success: function(data) {
                                if(Parametro ==null){
                                    window.location='test.php';
                                }
                            
                            }
                        });
                            
                        }else{
                            alert("Validate username or password");
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    alert("Validate username or password");
                }
           }
        });
    }else{
        alert("Please enter username or password");
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input id="username" type="text" name="username" class="form-control"  required/> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password:</label>
            <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="form-control"  required/>        
        </div>
         <button class="btn btn-default" id="login" onclick ="EnterLogin()">ENTER</button>
        </div>
```

The modal window that I want to open is the following:

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="modal fade" id="basicModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Basic Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <h3>Modal Body</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `$('#basicModal').modal('show');` on success function

Refrence [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13183713/9606095)

Comment: In which part of my function should I add `$('# basicModal'). Modal ('show');` ? You can add an example as an answer based on the code that I added in my initial question to validate your answer

Comment: @JohnDoe What do you want to show in modal?

Comment: @JohnDoe  if you want to show on success replace `window.location='test.php';` with `$('#basicModal').modal('show');`